# Prove the injectivity and differentiability of $x(u,v) = (u \cos(v), u \sin(v), \frac{u^2}{2}).$

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Prove the injectivity and differentiability of

$$x(u,v) = (u \cos(v), u \sin(v), \frac{u^2}{2})$$

where $u \in (0,\infty),$ $v \in (0,2\pi).$

What I really want to prove is that (U,x) is a simple surface.

where U=(0,inf)x(0,2$\pi$)

What I have: 
For the injectivity Let (u1,v1),(u2,v2) $\epsilon$ U

Got to prove x(u1,v1)=x(u2,v2) $\Rightarrow$ (u1,v1)=(u2,v2)

$\frac{u1^2}{2}$ = $\frac{u2^2}{2}$   $\Rightarrow$  u1=$\pm$u2

u1*cosv1 = u2*cosv2  $\Rightarrow$  ?

u1*senv1 = u2*senv2  $\Rightarrow$  ?

And I don't have any clue about how to prove differentiability

Comment: Please show us your work and show us specifically where you got stuck.

Comment: Haven't got too much

Comment: click on edit to see a few of the tricks in MathJax.

Comment: Observe that $u_1,  u_2>0$. Thus $\frac{u1^2}{2}=\frac{u2^2}{2}$ implies $u1=u2$.